# Image in Outlook sent item email changes to image from another email

Tags: excel, vba, image, email, outlook

I'm using Excel VBA to email images.

After I've sent the emails, the images in my sent items interchanges between different emails and it keeps happening.

e.g. I've sent an image with data related to `C1` region to `C1` recipients and `C1` recipients received it correctly. The image in my sent items and received by another cc recipient kept changing to `C2`, `C3`, `C4` every time we opened to check it.

Sent mail showing correct data of C1
[image]

Sent mail showing wrong data of C3
[image]

```vb
Sub C_1()
    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    'This macro use the function named : CopyRangeToJPG
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim MakeJPG As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Dear Sir" & "<br><br>" & _
        "Kindly find the retails performance dashboard for your reference." & "<br><br>" & _
        "Regards" & "<br>" & _
        "Manish Lengade<br>"

    'Create JPG file of the range
    'Only enter the Sheet name and the range address
    MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet 1", "B2:L15")

    If MakeJPG = "" Then
        MsgBox "Something go wrong, we can't create the mail"
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "manish.lengade@maruti.co.in"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Retails Performance Dashboard"
        .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 1
        'Note: Change the width and height as needed
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=1000 height=450></html>"
        .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    Dim PictureRange As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
        Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
        
        If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        PictureRange.CopyPicture
        With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
            .Activate
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
        End With
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    End With
    
    CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
    Set PictureRange = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I doubt there's any chance that anyone can help you unless you include the part of your code that causes the problem. And I don't mean just to dump all of your code (if there's a lot of it)

Comment: Hi James Z, I am unable to figure out which part of the code is causing this issue in my outlook mail. Enclosing used code below:

Comment: Please don't put any code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Just edited. This is the code I copied from link: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail0.htm

Comment: You're using the same file name, "NamePicture.jpg", for all of your emails. If you do things parallel, that definitely causes problems. How about adding this "C1" etc. into your file name?

Comment: Thanks James. Let me try and see....

Comment: Hi James Z, The above suggested solution worked. However, as I changed file name to C1 & so on, image overlapping stopped for same day sent mails but overlapping is happening for images of different dates. Is there a way I code in today's date as file name? Pls suggest.

Comment: Shouldn't you just delete the old files? Don't really see why you would keep them after the email is sent.

Comment: I have been deleting. However, my email recipients are facing this problem.

Comment: How could try receive a picture that's been deleted a day earlier? Of course you can add a date to the file name too.

Comment: Yes. Its surprising but it is happening with one of my recipient. He is receiving my mails with older date files whereas I have check my sent items, which is current date image.

Comment: Pls suggest on how to add todays' date as a file name in VB code.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to delete images after an email has been sent out. The `CopyRangeToJPG` method saves the generated chart as image to the disk, but after an email is sent out the image is left on the disk.

Also, if you want to get the same image attached to emails, it make sense to check out whether the temp folder already contains the generated earlier image.

Anyway, I'd recommend running the code under the debugger going through the code line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to uniquely identify each file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub C_1_Unique_FileName()

    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    'This macro uses the function named CopyRangeToJPG_Unique_FileName
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim MakeJPG As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    strbody = "Dear Sir" & "<br><br>" & _
      "Kindly find the retails performance dashboard for your reference." & "<br><br>" & _
      "Regards" & "<br>" & _
      "Manish Lengade<br>"
    
    Dim strNow  As String
    strNow = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss")
    Debug.Print strNow
    
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "NamePicture_" & strNow & ".jpg"
    
    Debug.Print fileName
    
    'Create JPG file of the range
    ' Sheet name, range address and filename
    'MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet 1", "B2:L15", filename)
    MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG_Unique_FileName("Sheet1", "B2:L15", fileName)
    
    If MakeJPG = "" Then
        MsgBox "Something went wrong, can't create the mail."
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With OutMail
        .Subject = "Retails Performance Dashboard"
        .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 1
        
        Dim htmlStr As String
        
        'Note: Change the width and height as needed
        'htmlStr = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=1000 height=450></html>"
        'Debug.Print htmlStr
        
        htmlStr = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:" & fileName & """ width=1000 height=450></html>"
        Debug.Print htmlStr
        
        .HTMLBody = htmlStr
        .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function CopyRangeToJPG_Unique_FileName(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String, fileName As String) As String

    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    Dim PictureRange As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
    
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
        Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        PictureRange.CopyPicture
        
        With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
            .Activate
            .Chart.Paste
            Debug.Print Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & fileName
            .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & fileName, "JPG"
        End With
        
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
        
    End With
    
    CopyRangeToJPG_Unique_FileName = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & fileName
    Debug.Print CopyRangeToJPG
    
    Set PictureRange = Nothing
    
End Function
```

With unique file names you may need to either manually clean up or add code to delete the file once the mail is generated.